# Подмена домена у запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть необходимость перенаправлять часть запросов на другой домен без изменений.

Быстро накидал "жёсткий" вариант по своей задаче, т.к. поиск не выдал сразу вразумительного решения.

Подскажите лучший способ реализовать перенаправление запросов в `C#`.

Код моего варианта:

```cs
public class RedirectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IAppSettings _settings;

    public RedirectMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IAppSettings settings)
    {
        _next = next;
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && HttpMethods.IsPost(context.Request.Method))
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_settings.AdapterUrl);
                var enc = context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ContentEncoding", out StringValues sv) ? Encoding.GetEncoding(sv.ToArray().First()) : Encoding.UTF8;

                var content = new StringContent(GetDocumentContents(context.Request, enc), enc, "application/json");

                var res = await client.PostAsync(context.Request.Path, content);

                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)res.StatusCode;
                context.Response.ContentType = res.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
                var respContent = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                context.Response.ContentLength = respContent.Length;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(respContent, enc);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    private string GetDocumentContents(HttpRequest request, Encoding enc)
    {
        string documentContents;
        using (Stream receiveStream = request.Body)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, enc))
            {
                documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return documentContents;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.5.php

Comment: @iluxa1810, не, это не то.